# Unable to add migration on dotnet

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, openiddict

Hello everyone I am trying to add migration on my project by following code

```
add-migration InitialCreate
```

I am the facing issue while adding migration. The error says

> Method not found:
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.IndexBuilder
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.EntityTypeBuilder`1.HasIndex

What's going on here. How to solve this????

Packages installed on my project
[image]

Comment: `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` is still on version 2.2.0 in your project.

Comment: @poke That's the latest version I can see. I can't update it

Comment: If your project Sdk is `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web`, then just remove the reference.

Comment: ASP.NET Core 3.0+ uses a framework reference instead of meta packages. Any NuGet packages without corresponding 3.0+ versions were rolled into the framework, so you no longer need to add a package reference directly. You *do* need the framework reference, though, so if you manually upgraded this project to 3.1, you might have missed that part.

Comment: @poke no that's not working instead causing a build error.

Comment: @ChrisPratt - I didn't get you. Can you elaborate it more. Which line of the core should I have to remove??

Comment: See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#framework-reference. Remove any 2.X `Microsoft.AspNetCore.*` packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might problen of version mismatching. Please update your Openiddict to `2.0.1` like

```
<PackageReference Include="OpenIddict" Version="2.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="OpenIddict.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="OpenIddict.Mvc" Version="2.0.1" />
```